# What is difference between server and a reverse proxy server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have been using nginx for a while but don't know exactly what is a reverse proxy server and what is the role of unicorn. Both are servers or they have different roles to play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your "normal" proxy usage. A bunch of computers want to get to the internet and their requests all go through a proxy server that can do caching, filtering, logging, throttling and a lot of other things.

[image: proxy server]

The reverse proxy setup looks pretty much the same, but the traffic flows in the **opposite direction** (hence the "reverse part"). A bunch of machines are sitting in your network and someone *from the internet* wants to access them. You could just expose the machines directly, but that would mean somehow letting the internet know about how to reach them. Not very practical. What usually happens is that you expose just one (or a few) gateway machines that hide all your app servers behind them and distribute requests to the app servers (a proxy, but in reverse, see?)

[image: reverse proxy]

> Both are servers or they have different roles to play.

"Server" is a very broad term. So yes, both are servers and they *serve* their separate roles. Nginx distributes requests, and unicorns fulfill the requests and generate response (which then flows through nginx back to the internet).